# Weird Process.Start behavior under NUnit

Tags: .net, nunit, process.start, plink

I'm using Process.Start on plink.exe to run a remote call on a Linux machine. This works well, unless run in the context of NUnit (I've tried both TestDriven.NET and ReSharper's unit test runner).

In the NUnit test, the process seems to close immediately and not actually do anything, like something is forcing it to close.

Here is the code, note that in the context of a console application, it works perfectly.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();          
processStartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Tools\plink\plink.exe";
processStartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh #some parameters here#;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

var process = new Process();

process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();            
var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you forgot:

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: But if that were needed, my console application wouldn't have worked as well, right?